# How to exclude Android Library project in ProGuard?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, proguard, eclipse-adt

I have an an Android application project that refers to an external library project. The Proguard in the application always fail with the following error message:

```
Proguard returned with error code 1. See console 

Error: Can't read [*](Can't process class [com/*/*/a.class] (Expected Utf8Constant at index
[6] in class [com/*/*/a]))
```

I tried several ways (such as -keep, -dontwarn, -injar etc..) to exclude the jar in the external library project that contains a.class, but unable to proceed.

What is the proper way of excluding external library projects that may also have one or more JARs in the libs?

Answer (score 0):

The class file seems corrupt; ProGuard really can't use it. Maybe it has been processed with some other tool? You can see if javap accepts it:

```
javap -classpath libs/library.jar com.x.y.a
```

If the file is not really a class file, the only solution is probably to remove it from the library.

Comment: javap accepted the class. Somebody found a work around for this case, can you please explain:

Comment: - Download the latest stable proguard archive

- from the extracted folder, I've open the file ClassConstants.java (location is ~/src/proguard/classfile)

- in the ClassConstants.java, I've changed the value of the constant ATTR_StackMapTable and set "dummy" (for the proguard 4.11, the ATTR_StackMapTable row is located line 174) and save it

Comment: - I run the build.sh file located in ~/build in order to generate the 3 jar file which will be create in the ~/libs folder

- In the ~/<eclipse folder="">/sdk/tools/proguard/lib, I've replaced the 3 jar file with the generated one from proguard 4.11 version